# Adding additional java files to playframework classpath

Tags: java, classpath, playframework

I have a project that shares models with my android project. I have a separate eclipse project just for models and other shared code. I add this to my play project as a dependency in eclipse.

In eclipse, play compiles and starts without problem. However, I went to deploy to GAE and found that the compilation stage of play's packaging fails because it can't find the models.

I suspect I could hack the ant build files, but that seems brittle.

Is there a standard way to add extra directories to the play compilation source tree or the classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a jar-file with your classes and put it in `/lib`. That's where I put my libraries.

Files in the application `/lib` folder is automatically added to the class path by Play Framework. See [Classpath settings](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/ide#Classpathsettings)

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I was hoping to not have to build a jar every time I wanted to build play's war. I'd have to wrap play's upload into another script which builds the jar. I guess that's not a problem, I was just hoping there was a nice quick solution.

Comment: Does having the jar in /lib interfere with eclipse? I'd have to make sure that the jar was not there when I eclipsify, otherwise eclipse might use this jar rather than the models from my other project.

Answer (score 0):

From [Anatomy](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/Anatomy#The-app/-directory): *"The app directory contains all executable artifacts: Java and Scala source code, templates and compiled assets’ sources"* ... and further: *"You can of course add your own packages, for example an app/utils package"*

You can copy java source files to make a hierarchy of packages under /app, e.g.:
/app/sharedcode/project2/models/domain1 and import that in WhateverController.scala as:

```
import sharedcode.project2.models.domain1._
```