# Play Framework -- add new directories to classpath

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I would like to be able to have a separate directory where jar files that represent plugins can be added to a Play 2.0 project.
Jar files are normally kept under the /lib directory in Play.  I'd like to separate my jars in a directory called /plugins

This question was asked before, but the suggestion was to just use the /lib directory.
[Adding additional java files to playframework classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731406/adding-additional-java-files-to-playframework-classpath)

Is there no way to do this without manually changing the 'eclipsified' files generated by Play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can do that by altering the sbt build script. Should be as simple as

`unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "custom_lib" }`

Here is the link to the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies).