# Move routing files into separate folder

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

For my project I have several routing files in the conf folder. I include them using `->  /api api.Routes`. 
I want to move all my routing files except the main routes file into a seperate folder within the conf folder so my folder layout would look something like this:

```
conf/
    routes
    routing/
         api.routes
         ...other routing files
```

Is there any way to reference these route files? I have searched the play documentation for this but unfortunately wasnt able to find anything. I also tried referencing it by the folder name like this:

```
->  /api routing/api.Routes
->  /api routing.api.Routes
```

Comment: Myabe, it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20211734/play-framework-split-routes-in-multiple-files-without-sub-projects?rq=1

Comment: Maybe `conf/routing` is not in the classpath. Maybe this can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692369/play-framework-add-new-directories-to-classpath